# Getting error: "invalid_client" when connecting Angular to IndentityServer4

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am getting invalid_client error when connecting Angular to IndentityServer4

Everything is okay when triggering it using Postman as shown below.

[image]

And this is how my Angular authservice connect to IdentityServer4. (shown below)

It will give me invalid_client error.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or have missed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpParams` is immutable (see: [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams))

So you have to do this instead:

```js
const body = new HttpParams()
   .set(...)
   .set(...)
   ...;
```

Comment: My goodness, you are a life saver. been searching this for hours. Thank you so much.